# jquery - add button that creates new select list without the previous selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create an add button that every time the user presses it, a new dropdown list will be created and the selected value won't be in the new dpl. Also the first dropdown list is getting the data from the database(this is done).

The code below has a button that each time it is pressed a new dpl should be created with all the previous values minus the one that the user chose but instead it creates just one dpl and that's it.

I tried doing this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073815/create-new-drop-downs-on-change-event-using-jquery) but it doesn't work! any tips?

Also, this is for practice so no need for validations etc etc.

**HTML CODE**

```
    <label id="services-L" for="services" class="label preField reqMark" style="width: 100px; min-width:0">Services</label><br>
    <select id="c_service" name="c_service" class="required  dynamic-select" style="width:170px" >
    <option value="">Select Service...</option>
    <?php
        $res=mysqli_query($conn,"Select t1 t2 Where t4s = 'Y'");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
        <option value = <?php echo $row['invoice_code']?> > <?php echo $row['t1'] . ": " . $row['t2'];}?> </option>
    ?>
    </select>  
<button type="button" id="btn_add_service>Add Service</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$('#btn_add_service').on('click', function() {  
    selected = $('#c_service').prop('selectedIndex');
    if (selected != 0 && $('#c_service').find('option').length != 2){
    newselector = $('<select id="c_service"></select>').insertAfter('#c_service');
    $('#c_service').find('option').each(function(index,item) {
      if (index != selected){
        $(newselector).append(item);
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: So what doesn't work exactly? Im not copying your code because I have no database that seeds it. Are you getting errors? What happens when you run this

Comment: So basically every time the user presses the button it should create a new select list with all the previous records minus the one chose. At the moment it is only creating just one select list and no more

Comment: I understand what it's supposed to do, but we're not here to help you find out why. That is your job. If you're stuck with a specific problem, we can help you with that. With your question in the current form, we cannot help you.

Comment: the problem is that I can't figure out why it just creates one dpl and not many..Do you see any errors in the code?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , and then the first enumerated point below: *Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:* You're asking us to do something for you that is *your* job. We're not here to debug your code, there's other forums online for that. Once you find and error or something concrete that you do not understand, come back, What you're asking help with is not something that is concrete, you're asking us to give you something concrete so that you can solve it. This is off topic

Comment: I asked for tips on how to solve it not the answer ready! Can't you read? I wrote what was the problem and I asked for help not someone to do it for me! if you are not going to help why comment or bother at all?

Comment: You literally asked me **Do you see any errors in the code?** . In the forum rules it states: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") * are off topic. Because I thought you needed some actual help I spend 10 minutes creating an answer. I discarded it now, and you wasted my time. The reason Im bothering telling you this is off topic is because I wan't you to stop wasting peoples time on this forum. Your question is not invalid, it just does not belong here. Don't be mad, this is your problem, not ours.

Comment: ok ok ok! :)   thanks very much for wasting your time!

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like this?
Having **master select** and provide some replicas?

```js
function ReplicaCtrl($) {
  const master = $('#MasterSelect');
  const btn = $('#btn_add_service');
  
  function serialize(select) {
    
    return Array
      .prototype
      .reduce
      .call(select.children(), 
      (res, item) => {
        return res.concat({
          value: item.value,
          label: item.textContent,
          selected: item.selected
        });
      }, [])
    ;
  }
  
  btn.click((event) => {
    
    return Promise
      .resolve(serialize(master))
      .then(options => {
        return options.filter(o => !o.selected);
      })
      .then(options => options.map(o => (
        `<option value="${o.value}">${o.label}</option>`
      )))
      .then(tpl => `<div><select>${tpl}</select></div>`)
      .then(select => $(select).insertAfter(master.parent()))
    ;
  });
}


jQuery(document).ready(ReplicaCtrl);
```

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: cyan;
}
select { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn_add_service">Add Service</button>
<hr />

<div>
  <select id="MasterSelect">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="foo1">Foo1</option>
    <option value="foo2">Foo2</option>
    <option value="foo3">Foo3</option>
    <option value="foo4">Foo4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, thank you! but what language is the first block written in? is it jquery?

Comment: while `jQuery` isn't a language, yes it is written on top of `jQuery`.

Comment: well yeah, you know what i meant. you used promises to achieve it but is there any more simplified way of doing it? something similar to what I am doing? as this is for practicing and I want to take it one step at a time @Hitmands

Comment: i haven't had any previous experience with them that's why I don't understand what they are doing

Comment: in this case, their purpose is just to provide a pipe: `Serialize => filter out selected => create option template => wrap in a select => append the select after the master select`